# Instance of 'Controller' has no 'type' member pynput module

Tags: python, pynput

I am fairly new to `Python`, I recently made this program to automatically click a text box in a program and type text (hello). But everytime I run the program, it says:

```
Instance of 'Controller' has no 'type' member.
```

I am using `pynput` and `Python 3.8.1 32bit`. I installed `pynput` manually through the console with

```
pip install pynput
```

Here is my code:

```
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller

def controlMouse(x, y):
    mouse = Controller()
    mouse.position = (x, y)

def controlKeyboard(txt):
    keyboard = Controller()
    keyboard.type(txt)

def clickMouse():
    mouse = Controller()
    mouse.click(Button.left, 1)

def pressKeyboard(key):
    keyboard.press(Key.key)
    keyboard.release(Key.key)

mouse = Controller()


controlMouse(268, 1030)
time.sleep(1)
clickMouse()
time.sleep(1)
controlMouse(400, 955)
time.sleep(1)
clickMouse()

controlKeyboard('Hello')
pressKeyboard(enter)
```

Comment: You're attempting to import two different things named `Controller` and the last one from `pynput.mouse` wins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
```

After that, `Controller` refers to `pynput.mouse.Controller` (because it was the last time `Controller` was defined). If you want to be able to refer to both `Controller` types, you should do something like this:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller as KeyboardController
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller as MouseController
```

You can then use `KeyboardController` and `MouseController` to refer to the right kind of `Controller`.

Alternatively, you can:

```
import pynput.keyboard
import pynput.mouse
```

You can then just refer to `pynput.keyboard.Controller` and `pynput.mouse.Controller`.